# Referencing a virtual directory in C#

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a webserver setup in iis called WebServer, in location ex. C:\inetpub\WebServer\  I have created a virtual directory call it virtualdir where the physical path is outside of the path of my webserver for example the Virtual directory points at C:\inetput\virtualdir, everything works fine and I can access files going to www.myserver.com/virtualdir/test.txt, however I was wondering if from my default.aspx page I can reference the virtual directory as part of my project like so

```
File.Exists("~/virtualdir/test.txt)
```

or do I have to reference the complete path of the virtual directory like so

```
File.Exists("C:/inetpub/virtualdir/test.txt")
```

Thank you,

Comment: use..File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/virtualdir/test.txt"))

Comment: So did any of this information help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert a relative, web based path containting the "~" to a path that file.exists can deal with. in order to do that call server map path to convert one to the other. See
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Consider including the useful part of code from that link, so if that page every disappears one day, your answer can still help people.